# RWD Theme, my account drop-down links

Tags: rwd-theme, rwd

Does anyone know the file where the RWD theme account dropdwon links

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
admin > System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront > yes
```

After this refresh your site front end.

You will get the correct information of file location. In RWD you can find it under :

```
app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\page\html\header.phtml
```